# Vectorization of Conditions( inside Loop)

Tags: matlab, performance, for-loop, if-statement, vectorization

For faster implementation , I would like to vectorize below matlab code :

```
   A=randi([0 1],20,20);
    B=zeros(20);
    for row = 5:15
     for column = 5:15
    if(A(row,column)==1 && (A(row+1,column)~=1 ||A(row,column+1)~=1)) 
      B(row,column)=1;
    end
     end
    end
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this one will work for you.

```
A=randi([0 1],20,20);    
B=zeros(20);    
z = find(A(5:15,5:15) == 1 & (A(6:16,5:15)~=1 | A(5:15,6:16)~=1));    
y = B(5:15,5:15);    
y(z) = 1;    
B(5:15,5:15) = y;
```

Comment: voted up and selected the answer, but your version of vectorization doesn't speed up much! ... average 3 mili sec :)

Comment: Now you are only using 20*20 matrix and the total time in the original case is around 0.003s which is really low. I think the speed up process will be much more visible for the large matrices.

Comment: I think @Zizy Archer's version is useful too if you just add all the logical expressions in one line. You can take a look at this too,

A=randi([0 1],20,20);
B=zeros(20);
row = 5:15;    
col = 5:15;    
allCond = (A(row, col) == 1) &((A(row+1, col) ~= 1) | (A(row, col+1) ~= 1));    
B(row, col) = double(allCond);

Comment: no, its not, I ran for 20000 times the average  difference (between loop and zizy's version) is 0.0008.... btw,  I tried substituting  find directly into y() without using z... didn't become faster....

Answer (score 2):

Just calculate all `A(row, column)==1` and such at once for the whole loop, then use ordinary boolean operations. This should work just fine for the case you presented (though short-circuiting stuff operates a little bit differently, so this might not be always possible).

```
row = 5:15;
col = 5:15;
firstCond = A(row, col) == 1;
secondCond = A(row+1, col) ~= 1;
thirdCond = A(row, col+1) ~= 1;
allCond = firstCond & (secondCond | thirdCond);
B(row, col) = double(allCond);
```

Comment: voted up, but the  this version of vectorization doesn't speed up much! ... average 3 mili sec :) ... a bit slower than amahmud 's version (see blow or up)...